# staging files modularly in Git

Tags: git

I have just started using Git. From my previous experience from using Perforce, I want to know if i can stage the files in sections of user stories/tasks so that I can commit only specific files ? If so how to do this. I might be working on different user stories at the same time.

Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: [This section](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository) of the Pro Git book should be illuminating. Also, you may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351450/what-does-adding-to-the-index-really-mean-in-git) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add to your index only specific file ([`git add -- afile`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)).

But you even can add specific portion of a file (`git add -p -- afile`), [up to a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6276752/6309).

In both case, adding to the index helps you to prepare the next commit.

Comment: But there is a single index. Can i Have more sections in a single index? Or label specific files inside the staging area?

Comment: @Pradeep no, you prepare one commit at a time. If your user stories can be developed independently one from another, you can consider branches (one branch per user stories, also called "feature branches")