# How can I make an individual commit message for each file (or even each part of a file) that has changed since the last commit

Tags: git

My preferred routine is to stage and commit my changed files all at once:

```
git commit -a
# enter commit message via editor
```

This works great when all of my changes are related to each other. However, when there are several unrelated changes (i.e. I forgot to make commits for each one), it makes for a lengthy commit message. In these cases, I'd rather have an individual commit message for each file, or even a separate commit message per change when there are multiple unrelated changes within a file. How can I do that?

---

#### Note: Difference between this and [How do I commit only some files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239333/how-do-i-commit-only-some-files)

My question is different because it also addresses multiple commits within a file.

Comment: General practice in this case would be to make a commit every time you complete one of those changes.

Comment: @TomasSmagurauskas Yes, of course that is the best practice. But sometimes I forget to commit. Updated question to include this fact. Great comment!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I commit only some files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239333/how-do-i-commit-only-some-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add a whole file, then use

```
git add file.txt
```

If you have separate changes within the same document that you want in separate commits, use a patch for selecting hunks

```
git add -p
```

When in interactive mode, if the hunks are too big, then you can split them by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>

After splitting, if you find that the hunks still aren't granular enough, then see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37769129/4233593) about manually editing it to create precision patches.

Comment: `git add -p` works very well. I just used it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply run `git stage` and `git commit` separately for each file:

```
git stage file1.txt
git commit
# use editor to type reasons for changing file1.txt

git stage file2.txt
git commit
# use editor to type reasons for changing file2.txt
```

See [Jeff Puckett II's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842053/215487) for how to commit sub-file level changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do a `git add -i` for an interactive staging, which lets you have fine grained control over what is introduced into the index. There is a full explanation of this option in the help output for git add and also a nice writeup at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging

Comment: Interactive staging is a really nice feature I didn't know about previously. Thanks!