# Why is split option missing in git add -p?

Tags: git, git-add

Trying to split a hunk into smaller ones by `git add -p` and `split` option, but entire file appears as one hunk and I can't split it.

1. I can edit, but removing lines causes the patch to fail.
2. `git help add` says I should have split, and I recall using it, but in my current example the option doesn't appear in the prompt.
3. When I choose the option help is printed, which says I can choose s to split :-[

Git version: 1.9.1. Xubuntu 14, oh-my-zsh. The hunk is not one line, it's multiple lines. Any ideas why would that be?

Edited with more data, here's console log:

```
+last line of long text 
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]? s
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit; do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining ones
a - stage this hunk and all later hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk nor any of the later hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

Comment: I believe you have to enter interactive mode (`-i`) first to use split.

Comment: Tried it out right away, but sadly - same effect. IIRC git add -p is just bypassing the original window for choosing options, it jumps straight to patching. Docs say the same (checked now). Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: That will be easier with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), which will display a more precise help message. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215261/6309).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because your hunk is already as small as git will automatically get it. Split only works when there are non-changed lines separating changed lines close enough that git assumes they belong together.

In order to achieve what you want, you will need to [manually edit the patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37769129/4233593)

Comment: Aahh! Non-changed lines separating changed ones, indeed. In that case I'll just split content without git and have it added in parts. /me thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Why is split option missing in `git add -p`?

You won't have to ask this question with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), since the **single-key help is now given only for keys that are enabled** (e.g. help for '`/`' won't be shown when there is only one hunk).

See [commit 4bdd6e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4bdd6e7ce33c72dfaa79c4139d30bd809ec8eda7), [commit 88f6ffc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88f6ffc1c256ef241cbed33dabbdd23c1a7ac6a9), [commit 01a6966](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01a6966021a50dc7aff76c0f951bbdd6e1bdd444) (13 Feb 2018) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 60f8b89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60f8b895180409303e11fa09c1405865365a70be), 06 Mar 2018)</sup>

First:

> ### `add -p`: improve error messages
>
> If the user presses a key that isn't currently active then explain why
>   it isn't active rather than just listing all the keys. It already did
>   this for some keys, this patch does the same for the those that
>   weren't already handled.

And:

> ### `add -p`: only display help for active keys
>
> If the user presses a key that `add -p` wasn't expecting then it prints
>   a list of key bindings.
>   Although the prompt only lists the active bindings the help was printed for all bindings.
>
> Fix this by using the list of keys in the prompt to filter the help.
>   Note that the list of keys was already passed to `help_patch_cmd()` by the caller so there is no change needed to the call site.

Comment: Upvoted! I'll leave accepted as it is for I believe right now more folks will benefit from it. Thank you @VonC nevertheless!

Comment: @LIttleAncientForestKami I agree: the accepted answer is still the right one.