# Does git stage hunk work differently on git for Windows?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

Aren't there some options missing from git for windows when you run `git add -p`?

```
+NOTE:
+
+* HIGHLIGHTED (grey) and ITALICIZED
+
+
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]? y
```

In linux there are options like split (`s`), etc..

My git version is:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.19.0.windows.1
```

Comment: `s` occurs when there are unchanged lines between changed parts. The changed parts are close enough to be treated as one hunk. In your case, the hunk has continuous changed lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in "[Why is split option missing in `git add -p`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215261/6309)", single-key help is now given only for keys that are enabled since Git 2.17 (March 2018).
Which explains why '`s`' it not visible here, since the hunk is too "compact" to be further split.

Which means your Git version in Linux is likely to be less than 2.17.
And your Git version on Windows is more up-to-date (although you could upgrade it to 2.21)